# How to remove text region in a document image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

Similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955513/how-to-detect-text-region-from-a-document-image), I want to ask the same question and see if there are other suggestions and ideas.

Given an document image (i.e. newspaper), how to extract photos in it or remove text region?

I think traditional OCR methods may not be suitable here, as I don't need to recognize the text, and OCR is not accurate and slow. I believe text region (i.e. text blocks) and image region should be distinguishable by some threshold based methods in image processing. Any suggestions or example codes in OpenCV will be appreciated. Thanks！

**BTW**, what if the background color is not white, or the background color of certain blocks are not white?

Example image:

[image]

Comment: You can try detecting rectangles in the image. Do some processing about size of the rectangle ( due to noise). This link can give you a good starting point https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/squares.cpp

Comment: You asked the question before, what's wrong with the provided answer?

Comment: You should have a good look at http://chris.improbable.org/2013/08/31/extracting-images-from-scanned-pages/ It's doing what you want to do, tested it on your image - gives some good results and it can help you understand the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Ocr doesnt take newspapers as input. It takes text regions that have to be found first. So it is indeed irrelevent. To find text regions one tipically uses adaptive thresholding ([tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html)) to binarize an image and then a stroke width transform with connected components to find cosistent text regions. See this paper, [swt](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.tau.ac.il%2F~turkel%2Fimagepapers%2Ftext_detection.pdf&rct=j&q=stroke%20width%20transform&ei=olrWVLiaPM6TNrCnhNAM&usg=AFQjCNHc4piIXiX1AYV3fwvr3Vc1UXJInA&sig2=5Eij2mtTfUaeAZf4nH3iyA).
Trying to find images seems to be harder an endeavor though they too have some distinct features such as less amount of high spatial frequencies compared to text.